# Add duplicates together in List

Tags: c#, list, duplicates, ienumerable

First question :)

I have a `List<Materiau>` (where `Materiau` implements `IComparable<Materiau>`), and I would like to remove all duplicates and add them together 
(if two `Materiau` is the same (using the comparator), merge it to the first and remove the second from the list)

A `Materiau` contains an ID and a quantity, when I merge two `Materiau` using `+=` or `+`, it keeps the same ID, and the quantity is added

I cannot control the input of the list.

I would like something like this:

```
List<Materiau> materiaux = getList().mergeDuplicates();
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You better implement IEquatable interface because your are looking for equality

Comment: Have you done any research yourself? The idea is you come up with a specific problem and some code you have a problem with, not to write a specification and sit back and wait for someone to write you a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry if I've ask incorrectly. Next time it will be better. Thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Linq](http://www.dotnetperls.com/groupby)! Specifically the `GroupBy` method.

I don't know how familiar you are with sql, but Linq lets you query collections similarly to how sql works.

It's a bit in depth to explain of you are totally unfamiliar, but [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35667/How-to-Use-LINQ-GroupBy) has a wonderful example

To sum it up:

Imagine we have this

```
List<Product> prodList = new List<Product>
{
    new Product
    {
        ID = 1,
        Quantity = 1
    },
    new Product
    {
        ID = 2,
        Quantity = 2
    },
    new Product
    {
        ID = 3,
        Quantity = 7
    },
    new Product
    {
        ID = 4,
        Quantity = 3
    }
};
```

and we wanted to group all the duplicate products, and sum their quantities.

We can do this:

```
var groupedProducts = prodList.GroupBy(item => item.ID)
```

and then select the values out of the grouping, with the aggregates as needed

```
var results = groupedProducts.Select( i => new Product
{ 
   ID = i.Key, // this is what we Grouped By above  
   Quantity = i.Sum(prod => prod.Quantity) // we want to sum up all the quantities in this grouping
});
```

and boom! we have a list of aggregated products

Comment: This worked just fine ! :D Thank you! This solved a lot of my others problems too (I just waited to see if my question was ok before posting something else -­> this one was not as mentionned by @charles-mager, next time it will be better)

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a class

```
class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

and a bunch of them inside a list

```
var foocollection = new List<Foo> {
    new Foo { Id = 1, Value = 1, },
    new Foo { Id = 2, Value = 1, },
    new Foo { Id = 2, Value = 1, },
};
```

then you can group them and build the aggregate on each group

```
var foogrouped = foocollection
    .GroupBy( f => f.Id )
    .Select( g => new Foo { Id = g.Key, Value = g.Aggregate( 0, ( a, f ) => a + f.Value ) } )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Materiau> distinctList = getList().Distinct(EqualityComparer<Materiau>.Default).ToList();
```